# newtx/newpx somehow interferes with font selection in certain case

Tags: errors, fontspec, newtx, newtxtext

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
% \usepackage{newpxtext}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{SourceHanSerifSC-Regular}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

There would be the error (with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX):

```
Package fontspec: The font "SourceHanSerifSC-Regular" cannot be found.
```

(detail with XeLaTeX)

```
Font TU/SourceHanSerifSC-Regular(0)/m/n/10=[SourceHanSerifSC-Regular.otf]/OT at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
<to be read again>
```

(detail with LuaLaTeX)

```
Font \TU/SourceHanSerifSC-Regular(0)/m/n/10=[SourceHanSerifSC-Regular.otf]:mode=node;language=dflt;-ss05;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax
```

However, without the package `newtxtext` or `newpxtext` loaded, `fontspec` can successfully find the font and the compilation is successful.

This seems to happen only with very recent version of `newtx` (v1.724, 2023/08/20) and `newpx` (v1.521, 2023/09/27).

What is happening here, and how can one fix this error?

> Sorry for using this CJK font, I cannot seem to produce the same error with other fonts.
> The font is got from https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/releases , the version I am using is the one called "Static Super OTC" — I'm not sure if this information is related.

> The MWE above didn't make use of `ctex` just to minimize the packages needed, as a result the CJK characters would be invisible. Below is the original MWE:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage{newtxtext}
> % \usepackage{newpxtext}
>
> \usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
>
> \setCJKmainfont{SourceHanSerifSC-Regular}
>
> \begin{document}
> Some text. 一些中文
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: luatex or xetex or both?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Both. Sorry that I forgot to mention.

Comment: I grabbed http://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/OTF/SimplifiedChinese/SourceHanSerifSC-Regular.otf (not sure if that is best place) and placed it in same directory as the test document then both newtx and newpx worked in both xelatex and luatex (cygwin texlive 2023)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually when I posted this question I had the newest version of `newtx` but not the newest version of `newpx`. A few minutes ago I updated all packages to the latest, and it seems that the new `newpx` also triggers the error.

Comment: hang on let me do a tlmgr update.....

Comment: `tlmgr update --all`  updated newpx and rebuilt all the formats and same thing, all four versions with lua/xe and px/tx worked, sorry I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your effort! Since I am still experiencing the errors, I tried to simplify the MWE, and have added some details include where did I got the font file and which version is being used (though not sure if this added information is actually related).

Comment: ah OTC version, they are trickier beasts, I'll try again over the weekend too late tonight here:-)

Comment: Sorry I can't test now but my first guess would be that newtx is setting some default font feature that disturbs following font settings. Try to clear the features (see the fontspec documentation)

Comment: I got the otc font, and fc-list says it contains the requested font `SourceHanSerif.ttc: Source Han Serif SC,思源宋体:style=Regular` but neither luatex nor xetex can see it at all (with or without newpx) this is cygwin texlive

Answer (score 1):

Rather than mixing obsolete 8-bit font packages with modern Unicode fonts, I recommend using the Unicode versions of all your fonts.  This cuts the Gordian Knot of so many compatibility problems.

Since another answer already discusses XeCJK, I’ll give an example in LuaLaTeX using Babel.  This would be appropriate for a mostly-English document with some words and phrases in Chinese.

Here is a version using clones of Palatino (also tweaked to work with the OTC version of Source Han Serif, but in practice you probably want to put any non-standard fonts in a `./fonts` subdirectory).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import=zh-hans, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\defaultfontfeatures[SourceHanSerifSC]{
    Ligatures=Common,
    UprightFont={* Medium},
    BoldFont={* Bold}
}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}
          {SourceHanSerifSC}
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % If you would need newpxmath.

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text. 一些中文 \\
\textbf{Some bold text. 一些中文}
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Pagella + Source Han Serif sample]

And of Times:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import=zh-hans, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\defaultfontfeatures[SourceHanSerifSC]{
    Ligatures=Common,
    UprightFont={* Medium},
    BoldFont={* Bold}
}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}
          {SourceHanSerifSC}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math} % If you would need newtxmath.

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text. 一些中文 \\
\textbf{Some bold text. 一些中文}
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Termes + Source Han Serif sample]

Comment: Thank you for this! It is nice to know that `babel` can handle Chinese to some extent. I always thought that the only way would be to use the huge package `ctex`. However I'm curious about what you mentioned "some words and phrases in Chinese". Would there be some issue if one type a document in mostly Chinese using this method?

Comment: @Jinwen Babel has the option to set Chinese (traditional or simplified) as the main language.Use `\babelprovide[import=zh-hans, main, onchar=fonts ids]{chinese}`, then whatever other languages you need. I could not tell you how the resulting layout would look to a native speaker of Chinese, but it should display without errors. Try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `xecjk` or `ctex` package instead of the `fontspec` package, and invoke the `newtxtext` or `newpxtext` package after the `xecjk` or `ctex` package. Also use `\setCJKmainfont` instead of `\setmainfont`.

```
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}%
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}%or ctex package for Chinese documents
\setCJKmainfont{SourceHanSerifSC-Regular}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage{newpxtext}


\begin{document}
Some text 中国
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminding. I was just trying to simplify the minimal working example so I removed the use of `ctex` which is rather a huge package. Also, your code doesn't seem to work on my side, I am getting `Option clash for package fontspec`. Are you using the newest version of `newtxtext`?

Comment: I updated all my packages, and the MWS I give works well for me. For the clash, add `\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}%` at the first line. I revised the codes.

Comment: By the way, don't use `newtxtext` or `newpxtext` to set English letters together with Chinese fonts in the document since the line weights of them are greater than most of Chinese regular fonts. The default computer modern font family for English letters is a better choice.

Comment: Why load `fontspec` before `\documentclass`? Could you explain?

Comment: Thank you for the edited version, it works. I'm still interested in some other way that can load `newtxtext` before `ctex` though, since in my class `einfart` etc. the English font is configured before CJK font and it would be hard for me to modify this part of code at this stage. Also, regarding line weights, thank you for the reminding of this. It is just that my document class would configure all the supported language so even if one is writing in pure English, `ctex` and the CJK fonts are still being loaded and configured.

Comment: @cfr Loading `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` after`\documentclass` is also ok.

Comment: @Jinwen Then `polyglossia` may give a solution which can set English to be the main language.

Comment: @M.Logic With `einfart` etc. it is possible to set any supported language as the main language (essentially with `babel`). It is just that, unless explicitly stated that English would be the only language to be used (e.g. by adding `English` as class option), all the language would be preconfigured so that the user can always use `\UseLanguage` to switch the language in the middle of the document. On the other hand, I remember that two years ago `polyglossia` had some minor issue with French, I'm not sure if it has been fixed as of today, but `babel` is already good enough for my purposes.