# newtx package interferes with ctex (fontspec option clash)

Tags: fontspec, newtx, ctex

The **latest** version of `newtx` interferes with `ctex`, here's an MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

Hello, 你好.

\end{document}
```

I have upgraded to the latest version of `newtx` (1.732, Nov 6 2023) via `tlmgr`, and I got the following error when compiling with XeLaTeX:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package fontspec.
```

However, when compiled on Overleaf (here's my [Overleaf project link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/nzsvxbqshnpj#8f98e8)), it works perfectly fine.

By experimenting with Tex Live 2022, I find that only the latest version of `newtx` has this issue.

Is it a bug, or am I not using it correctly?

After reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697284/261113) (for `\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}`) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640393/261113) (for `\defaultfontfeatures{}`), I come up with the following workaround, which works well:

```
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\defaultfontfeatures{}

\begin{document}

Hello, 你好.

\end{document}
```

But a command before `\documentclass` is annoying. In addition, I really don't know why this works.

Since I'm writing a template for others, I wonder if this is a robust workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it didn't before or it does now, but `newtxtext` wants to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

Perhaps there's a native CTEX method, but the following workaround seems to do the job:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

Hello, 你好.

\end{document}
```